# Java: Get first item from a collection

Tags: java, collections, iterable

If I have a collection, such as `Collection<String> strs`, how can I get the first item out? I could just call an `Iterator`, take its first `next()`, then throw the `Iterator` away. Is there a less wasteful way to do it?

Comment: Of course there may be a better way to access the first element if you know the implementing container class...

Comment: Generalization for any index: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047957/best-way-to-get-value-from-collection-by-index

Comment: It sounds like you need Queue.peek()

Comment: Since Java 21 you can use [Collection.getFirst()](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431) (if your collection is `SequencedCollection` which is very likely)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

[Iterables.get(yourC, indexYouWant)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#get(java.lang.Iterable,%20int))

Because really, if you're using Collections, you should be using Google Collections.

Comment: That does the same thing, it just checks if it is a list first, and gets by index if it is. It also has some code to try to fail faster on an actual Collection (that is if the index is too large it tries to figure that out without iterating through the whole thing and throwing the exception at the end).

Comment: Honestly, performance-wise it might be slightly slower than c.iterator().next() - but the code is much clearer and simpler to modify.

Comment: I certainly agree it is cleaner, but the OP was about wasteful, but I guess since your answer was accepted that is what was desired.

Comment: For those (still) arriving here: I think jheddings' answer is probably the best "get it done" answer, though I'd prefer @DonaldRaab's (way down the page) for cases where I'm already using the GC library.  My answer is really for the case where one may want to write in flexibility for later (say, if one decides that the *second* element is the new hotness).

Comment: From Comments of the command:

Returns the first element in iterable or defaultValue if the iterable is empty. The Iterators analog to this method is Iterators.getNext(java.util.Iterator<? extends T>, T).
If no default value is desired (and the caller instead wants a NoSuchElementException to be thrown), it is recommended that iterable.iterator().next() is used instead.
So, no default value needed then use iterable.iterator().next()!

Comment: Sometimes you're just using code that uses Collections, so there's not much to do.

Comment: the answer is not applicable for the question

Comment: 2020 and still using a Google collections is a must?

Answer (score 553):

Looks like that is the best way to do it:

```
String first = strs.iterator().next();
```

Great question...  At first, it seems like an oversight for the `Collection` interface.

Note that "first" won't always return the first thing you put in the collection, and may only make sense for ordered collections.  Maybe that is why there isn't a `get(item)` call, since the order isn't necessarily preserved.

While it might seem a bit wasteful, it might not be as bad as you think.  The `Iterator` really just contains indexing information into the collection, not a usually a copy of the entire collection.  Invoking this method does instantiate the `Iterator` object, but that is really the only overhead (not like copying all the elements).

For example, looking at the type returned by the `ArrayList<String>.iterator()` method, we see that it is `ArrayList::Itr`.  This is an internal class that just accesses the elements of the list directly, rather than copying them.

Just be sure you check the return of `iterator()` since it may be empty or `null` depending on the implementation.

Comment: It is important to note that this "trick" only works when the collection actually has contents. If it's empty the iterator might return an error, in which one has to check the collection size beforehand.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. I do not understand why the answer is always "use another library!" .

Comment: not safe enough, it's not guaranteed that collection will always point to the 1st element.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer: simple and no additional requirements.

Answer (score 107):

In java 8:

```
Optional<String> firstElement = collection.stream().findFirst();
```

For older versions of java, there is a getFirst method in Guava [Iterables](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#getFirst-java.lang.Iterable-T-):

```
Iterables.getFirst(iterable, defaultValue)
```

Comment: The java 8 solution is especially useful, because it handles the case where the collection is empty gracefully.

Comment: Not good. You add overhead of stream() to get a get(0) just because you are lazy to write 4 lines of code.
    
    if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(productList)){
      return Optional.of(productList.get(0));
    }
    return Optional.empty();

Comment: I don't have `getFirst` method available. There are `get` and `getLast` methods

Comment: @R.S and what happens if you can't call productList.get(0), as it's a Collection..? (As per OP question)

Answer (score 45):

There is no such a thing as "first" item in a `Collection` because it is .. well simply a collection.

From the Java doc's [Collection.iterator()](http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator()) method:

> *There are no guarantees concerning the order in which the elements are returned...*

So you can't.

If you use **another** interface such as **List**, you can do the following:

```
String first = strs.get(0);
```

But directly from a Collection this is not possible.

Comment: I don't think `get(int n)` is defined for `Collection`

Comment: You're right, I miss that point. I have updated the answer. You can't! (unless the Collection is implemented by some underlaying class that allows provides the guarantee )

Comment: get is not in the Collection interface

Comment: @arghena: Yeap. I have updated the answer to emphasize the alternative.

Comment: @Oscar:  sorry, I must've posted before I saw your edit (I thought my comment was first in fact).  My browser must've been slow :P

Comment: Oscar, I think you're overstating the case. The first element of a Collection may be arbitrary in a few cases like HashSet, but it is well-defined: it's .iterator().next(). It's also *stable*, in every collection implementation I've ever seen.

(related: note that while Set doesn't guarantee order, every single subtype of Set in the JDK except HashSet does.)

Comment: It might be, but consider the case when you add a new element to the collection, you don't know ( by the interface ) if that element is the first, the last, or it would be inserted in the middle. For precise results you should use another interface. Yet, probably what Rosarch needs is the 1st element no matter what.  Knowing the underlaying collection may help, but it prevent you from changing it.

Comment: Good point. But, sometimes it maybe necessary to pull any random one. Even if the "first one" is not always the same, the advantage to knowing its the first one is you'll know (or at least hope, not a java expert) that the entire collection has been iterated through, wasting resources and time.

Comment: -1: The `n`th item of any `Iterable` is easily well-defined. When working with a `List`, you have additional guarantees that the operation is stable (and can often be performed in O(1) time), but it doesn't change the definition of the `n`th item of an `Iterable`.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like your Collection wants to be List-like, so I'd suggest:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
...
String first = myList.get(0);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Apache Commons Collections 4 there is an [`IterableUtils.first`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/IterableUtils.html#first-java.lang.Iterable-) method. It contains an optimization in the case of `List`s and is neat to use. It's very similar to the Guava method. The code would look like

```
String firstStr = IterableUtils.first(strs);
```

Answer (score 3):

Functional way:

```
public static <T> Optional<T> findFirst(List<T> result) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(result)
            .map(List::stream)
            .flatMap(Stream::findFirst);
}
```

above code snippet preserve  from NullPointerException and IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Your choice of `List<T>` doesn't satisfy the condition that it should work for a `Collection<String>`, but of course that can be fixed using `Collection<T>`, with the additional change: `.map(Collection::stream)`.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 you have some many operators to use, for instance **limit**

```
     /**
 * Operator that limit the total number of items emitted through the pipeline
 * Shall print
 * [1]
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
@Test
public void limitStream() throws InterruptedException {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3)
                               .stream()
                               .limit(1)
                               .collect(toList());
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Comment: @Vitalii Fedorenko's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18165855/1562662 is better.

Answer (score 2):

Guava provides an `onlyElement` `Collector`, but only use it if you expect the collection to have exactly one element.

```
Collection<String> stringCollection = ...;
String string = collection.stream().collect(MoreCollectors.onlyElement())
```

If you are unsure of how many elements there are, use `findFirst`.

```
Optional<String> optionalString = collection.stream().findFirst();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a casting. For example, if exists one method with this definition, and you know that this method is returning a List:

```
Collection<String> getStrings();
```

And after invoke it, you need the first element, you can do it like this:

```
List<String> listString = (List) getStrings();
String firstElement = (listString.isEmpty() ? null : listString.get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the collection is a queue then you can cast the collection to a queue and get it easily.

There are several structures you can use to get the order, but you will need to cast to it.

Comment: I agree, if you don't wanna iterate, don't use collection. Use some other more specific interface instead.

Comment: I wonder though...let's say the actual underlying data is a SortedSet, so order makes sense, but you only have a Collection view of it (for a non-silly reason, let's say); if you cast the Collection to a List, Queue, etc and try to get/poll/etc, does disaster ensue?  Likewise, if underlying structure is a List, so on, so forth.

Comment: @Cal - I haven't tried it, but if you cast a collection into a very different type than it was originally you should get an error, but, I haven't tried it, so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends upon which implementation you have used, whether arraylist linkedlist, or other implementations of set.

if it is set then you can directly get the first element , their can be trick loop over the collection , create a variable of value 1 and get value when flag value is 1 after that break that loop.

if it is list's implementation then it is easy by defining index number.

Answer (score -1):

I used this:

```
strs.isEmpty() ? "" : strs.iterator().next();
```

Answer (score -3):

You could do this:

```
String strz[] = strs.toArray(String[strs.size()]);
String theFirstOne = strz[0];
```

The javadoc for Collection gives the following caveat wrt ordering of the elements of the array:

> If this collection makes any guarantees as to what order its elements are returned by its iterator, this method must return the elements in the same order.

Comment: This creates a new String array, much more expensive than creating an iterator.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that after I posted this.  Regardless of the method used, ordering depends on the underlying implementation of the Collection.  "First" then becomes a relative term.

However, the iterator() way of doing it is probably better in most cases.

Comment: I came here because this was the solution I had and found ugly.