# What's the best way to extract a single value from a Set in groovy?

Tags: groovy, set

If I have a Set that I know contains a single element, what's the best way to extract it?  The best I can come up with is this, but it doesn't feel very groovy:

```
set = [1] as Set
e = set.toList()[0]
assert e == 1
```

If I'm dealing with a list, I've got lots of nice ways to get the element, none of which seem to work with Sets:

```
def list = [1]
e = list[0]
(e) = list
e = list.head()
```

Comment: The 'groovy feel' is a very subjective thing. If I were writing the code, I will be happy with `set.toList().first()`. :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A few alternatives, none of them very pretty:

```
set.iterator()[0]
set.find { true }
set.collect { it }[0]
```

Finally, if it's guaranteed that that set has only one item:

```
def e
set.each { e = it }
```

The underlying issue, of course, is that Java Sets provide no defined order (as mentioned in [the Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)), and hence no ability to get the nth element (discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769731/why-doesnt-java-util-set-have-getint-index) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671378/java-get-first-item-from-a-collection)). Hence, any solution is always to somehow convert the set to a list.

My guess is that either of the first two options involve the least data-copying, as they needn't construct a complete list of the set, but for a one-element set, that should hardly be a concern.

Comment: There is [Collection.find()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#find()) method since 1.8.1, which is a bit shorter to use than `set.find{ true }`

Answer (score 20):

One other possibility (which will work in Java or Groovy):

```
set.iterator().next()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 8, here is another solution that will work for both Java and Groovy:

```
set.stream().findFirst().get()
```

Answer (score 1):

Even when this question is quite old, I am sharing my just a bit prettier solution.

```
(set as List).first()
(set as List)[0]
```

If you need to take null into account (not the case in this question):

```
(set as List)?.first()
(set as List)?.get(index)
```

Hope it helps! :)