# Getting the first (and only value) from a collection

Tags: java, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Get first item from a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671378/java-get-first-item-from-a-collection)

In Java, I often encounter a collection with one single element, which I need to retrieve. Because collections do not guarantee consistent ordering, there is no `first()` or `get(int index)` methods, so I need to use rather ugly things, such as:

```
public Integer sillyExample(Collection<Integer> collection){
    if(collection.size()==1){
        return collection.iterator().next();
    }
    return someCodeToDecideBetweenElements(collection);
}
```

So, how do *you* get the only element out? I can't believe there isn't a better way...

Please note, I understand there's no concept of "first", I'm just trying to avoid building an iterator when I know there is only one element in it.

EDIT: Peter Wooster found a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671378/java-get-first-item-from-a-collection). I'm leaving this open because I'm not trying to get the "first" element, which would imply a consistent ordering, but the "one and only" element after checking that it indeed is the only element.

Comment: Exactly like this, except I wouldn't dare call `size()`. `Iterator<Integer> it = collection.iterator(); return it.hasNext()? it.next() : null;` and now you can go to an even more general `Iterable`.

Comment: hm, counter-question. What do you do if it does not have a single item? Wouldnt iterate over all elements all the time be waaaay safer than using this hack?

Comment: it's actually a good thing that `Collection` does not offer `first() `or `get(int)`, since a collection is generally unordered, and there is no "first" element

Comment: you could construct an ArrayList from it, but that;s ugly too.

Comment: Here's an old post on this topic:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671378/java-get-first-item-from-a-collection

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik "dare call size()"? Do you see any danger there? I simply check the size because the treatment I need to give the collection is different if I just have to return the one element, or make a choice between the two. I alter the code to reflect it.

Comment: I would do it like in Marko Topolnic's comment above, just with a generic method signature.

Comment: @Miquel If calling some method, clearly the right one is `isEmpty`; `size` requests more information from the collection than you need and may entail calculating the size, which the collection didn't know in advance. For example, what if it is a lazy-loaded collection from Hibernate, or anything like that?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yes, but I don't want to know if it's empty, I want to know if it has exactly one element

Comment: Aha, you want to **assert** it has only one element? Then do `Iterator<Integer> it = collection.iterator(); Integer ret = it.hasNext()? it.next() : null; if (it.hasNext()) return someCodeToDecideBetweenElements(collection);`

Comment: @Jayamohan yeap, my apologies. Peter Wooster found the original. I've added it to the question, and I going to vote to close it.

Comment: @Miquel That other question doesn't require the assertion you have mentioned. If you make that additional request clear in your question, then you don't have a duplicate.

Comment: Also take into account that "building an iterator" is not really a good paradigm: the iterator is a very lightweight object, designed to be created at will with negligible performance impact.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The easiest answer is what you've done!

```
first = collection.iterator().next();
```

note that iterator() is a method, was that a typo?

Comment: Thanks Peter! And yeah, I forgot the () in iterator ;) Fixed now.

Comment: Why is the accepted answer is the one that doesn't cover the "only value" part of the question?

Answer (score 16):

Have you ever looked at Google Guava? If you know that the collection has one element **only**, you can use `Iterables.getOnlyElement(collectionWithOneElement);` but if you don't know but still only want the first element you can use `getFirst(Iterable, T default)`. It will also return a default value you define if its empty.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know the method, but I just checked it and it's internally doing `return iterators.getOnlyElement(iterable.iterator());` so it's still building an iterator internally

Comment: ...and what it does with the iterator is entirely predictable, too, just as in my comment under the question. This may be a reassurance to you that this approach is the best.

Answer (score 2):

Its as simple as it is,

```
 Iterator<Integer> itr = collection.iterator(); 
 Object firstObj = itr.hasNext()? itr.next() : null;
```