# Is there a functional programming way to retrieve the first element of a collection?

Tags: groovy

The list can be empty. I would like to do :

```
def value = "";
def list = getList()
if (!list.isEmpty()){
   value = list.first().foo 
}
```

for instance I have found this way :

```
assert ( [].find()?.foo?:"empty" ) == "empty"
assert ([[foo:"notEmpty1"], [foo:"notEmpty2"]].find()?.foo?:"empty") == "notEmpty1"
```

Is there a better way ?

Thanks! :)

EDIT:

I got great answer by using `[0]`

```
assert ( [][0]?.foo?:"empty" ) == "empty"
assert ([[foo:"notEmpty1"], [foo:"notEmpty2"]][0]?.foo?:"empty") == "notEmpty1"
```

Comment: and why not `list?.get(0)`

Comment: list is not null but can be empty. So `list?.get(0)` will throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: If it is not a `List` but a `Collection` read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671378/java-get-first-item-from-a-collection

Comment: I agree I can use external lib like guava, but i'm looking for a 100% groovy solution.

Comment: In the same post you have it. As groovy can use the libraries of java a java solution is a groovy solution. 100%

Answer (score 0):

If it is a `List` just try

```
if (!list?.isEmpty()){
    list.get(0);
}
```

If the list element cannot be null you don't need the `?`

If it is a Collection there are several forms to retrieve it. Take a look at this post

[Java: Get first item from a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671378/java-get-first-item-from-a-collection)

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from tweeter. The statements :

```
def value = "";
def list = getList()
if (!list.isEmpty()){
   value = list.first().foo 
}
```

Can be write :

```
def value = list[0]?.foo?:""
```

`find` may be use if the list can contain null values