# get element of Collection knowing the index?

Tags: java, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [best way to get value from Collection by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047957/best-way-to-get-value-from-collection-by-index)

Say I have a [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). And I need to get the element at index 2.

How would I do this if there's no get method and iterator doesn't track indexes?

Comment: Collection is just an interface, which collection are you using?

Comment: Unless you have an ordered List or a sorted Set, getting an element at index 2 could be meaningless.

Comment: Perhpas it would be better to use a list if you want to keep an order.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First and foremost try to exploit the actual implementation. If it's a `List` you can downcast and use better API:

```
if(collection instanceof List) {
  ((List<Foo>)collection).get(1);
}
```

But the "*pure*" solution is to create an `Iterator` and call `next()` two times. That's the only general interface you have:

```
Iterator<Foo> fooIter = collection.iterator();
fooIter.next();
Foo second = fooIter.next();
```

This can be easily generalized to k-th element. But don't bother, there is already a method for that: [`Iterators.html#get(Iterator, int)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#get%28java.util.Iterator,%20int%29) in Guava:

```
Iterators.get(collection.iterator(), 1);
```

...or with [`Iterables.html#get(Iterable, int)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#get%28java.lang.Iterable,%20int%29):

```
Iterables.get(collection, 1);
```

If you need to do this many, many times, it might be cheaper to create a copy of the collection in `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Foo> copy = new ArrayList<Foo>(collection);
copy.get(1); //second
```