# Iterating a collection of Javabeans as an arraylist?

Tags: java

Originally I have been using arraylists like this:

```
ArrayList<JavaBean> AllBeans = new ArrayList<JavaBean>();
```

And I'm able to iterate through it and get it to print all of my beans like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<AllBeans.size();i++){
            System.out.println(AllBeans.get(i).getCost());
        }
```

But I found out I should be doing this:

```
Collection<JavaBean> AllBeans = new ArrayList<JavaBean>();
```

But if I do that, I no longer can do AllBeans.get(i).getCost(), [so I read on stackoverflow, and I apparently need to user an iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047957/best-way-to-get-value-from-collection-by-index). But, I don't understand what I'm doing. I want to be able to use the original bean classes, but I can't get to them? I just want to use my bean.getCost() from my bean object.

The only thing I could get was

```
Iterator itr = new AllBeans.Iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(itr.next().toString())
        }
```

Which doesn't get to my object at all? I'm still having trouble understanding abstract and interface in java.

Comment: What is a `woz`? Why do you expect the iterator of a new `woz` to be anything other than empty?

Comment: off topic but your sentence made my day: _But, I don't understand what I'm doing:

Comment: `Iterator<JavaBean> itr = AllBeans.Iterator();`.

Comment: @AndyTurner was renaming the variables for this question to make it make a bit more sense, but forgot to rename that one. Fixed it to AllBeans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an iterator you can get your object

```
Collection<JavaBean> AllBeans = new ArrayList<JavaBean>();
Iterator<JavaBean> itr = AllBeans.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(itr.next().getCost());
}
```

If you use just `Iterator itr` instead of `Iterator<JavaBean> itr` then you need to cast the object returned by `itr.next();`

```
Iterator it = AllBeans.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    JavaBean bean = (JavaBean)it.next();
    System.out.println(bean.getCost());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Collection<JavaBean> AllBeans = new ArrayList<JavaBean>();
AllBeans.get(i).getCost();
```

It was not working because `AllBeans` is a variable of type `Collection` which doesn't have `get` method. You can use

```
List<JavaBean> AllBeans = new ArrayList<JavaBean>();
AllBeans.get(i).getCost();
```

References:

`java.util.Collection`:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this because `Collection` has no index while `List` has. `Iterator` is also generic so you can use it like this:

```
Iterator<JavaBean>  itr = AllBeans.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(itr.next().getCost());
}
```

The easier way is to use the enhanced for loop (aka for-each loop)

```
for (JavaBean bean : AllBeans){
    System.out.println(bean.getCost());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [foreach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) Java statement

```
List<JavaBean> allBeans = new ArrayList<JavaBean>();
...
for (JavaBean bean: allBeans) {
   System.out.println(bean.getCost());
}
```

Also use Java identification convention: don't use uppercase for the first identification char. Use [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) convention.

If you use **Java 8** the statement may be even simpler and [flexible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html)

```
...
allBeans.stream()
    .map(bean -> bean.getCost())
    .forEach(System.out::println)
...
```